# The loss will be Nan when I use loss function defined by torch.nn.function.mse_loss

Tags: pytorch

The loss is always Nan when I use the loss function as follow:

```
def Myloss1(source, target):
    loss = torch.nn.functional.mse_loss(source, target, reduction="none")
    return torch.sum(loss).sqrt()

...

loss = Myloss1(s, t)
loss.backward()
```

But when I use the following loss function, the training becomes normal:

```
def Myloss2(source, target):
    diff = target - source
    loss = torch.norm(diff)
    return loss
...

loss = Myloss2(s, t)
loss.backward()
```

Why can't use the ‘Myloss1’ to train？ Aren't Myloss1 and Myloss2 equivalent?

Please help me，thank you very much！

Answer (score 0):

`Myloss1` and `Myloss2` are indeed supposedly equivalent. They at least return the same values for all the tensors I have tried them on.

About the Nan, let's first try to find when it happens. The only possible culprit here is the `sqrt`, which is not differentiable in 0. And indeed :

```
y = torch.randn(2,3)
x = y.clone()
x.requires_grad_(True)
Myloss1(x,y).backward()
print(x.grad.data)
>>> [[nan, nan, nan], [nan, nan, nan]]
```

On the other hand :

```
Myloss2(x,y).backward()
print(x.grad.data)
>>> [[-0., -0., -0.],[-0., -0., -0.]]
```

Of both results, only the first is mathematically "accurate". Computing the derivative of the square root at 0 yields a division by 0. That is why when training neural networks or whatever, the `sqrt` is not used. You should use

```
good_loss = torch.nn.MSELoss(reduction='mean') # or ='sum' if you prefer
```

This function is differentiable everywhere, you won't have any more trouble.

As to why your `Myloss2` yields a different gradient, it is related to its implementation. It was extensively discussed [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/nan-in-torch-norm-if-input-is-zero/6844). Basically, people complained about the nans, so the lib was changed to modify this behavior, while acknowledging that there is no mathematically correct answer here since this derivative is not defined at 0.